# property getter or setter expected in Kotlin ViewModel class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have following ViewModel class :

```
class PersonViewModel(
        context: Application,
        private val dataSource: MoviesRemoteDataSource)
    : AndroidViewModel(context) {

    internal val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    val person: ObservableField<Person>()
    private val isVisible = ObservableBoolean(false)

    fun showPerson(personId: String) {
        val personSubscription = dataSource.getPerson(personId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ person ->
                    isVisible.set(true)
                    this.person.set(person)
                }
                ) { throwable -> Timber.e(throwable) }

        compositeDisposable.add(personSubscription)
    }
}
```

And this is Person class :

```
class Person(
        @SerializedName("birthday")
        var birthDay: String?,
        @SerializedName("deathday")
        var deathDay: String?,
        var id: Int,
        @SerializedName("also_known_as")
        var alsoKnowAs: List<String>,
        var biography: String,
        @SerializedName("place_of_birth")
        var placeOfBirth: String?)
```

It shows an error on this line in ViewModel:

```
val person: ObservableField<Person>()
```

It says : `property getter or setter expected`

I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Most likely, replace:

```
val person: ObservableField<Person>()
```

with:

```
val person = ObservableField<Person>()
```

This sets up `person` to be initialized with the `ObservableField<Person>` that you are creating.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 4):

looking at your code:

```
val person: ObservableField<Person>()
```

you have a simple **syntax error** the **parentheses after type!** remove them or change colon to assign sign:

```
val person: ObservableField<Person>
```

or

```
val person = ObservableField<Person>()
```